# Resolving ruby dependencies via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to update to rails 5, and am running into some dependency issues. Bundler is giving me some output that looks like:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “faraday”:
  In Gemfile:
    my_gem was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.9.0)

my_gem was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
  faraday-http-cache (~> 0.4.2) was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
    faraday (~> 0.8)

my_gem was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
  faraday_middleware (~> 0.9.1) was resolved to 0.9.2, which depends on
    faraday (< 0.10, >= 0.7.4)
```

If I'm reading this properly, we need a version of faraday that is:

```
>= 0.9.0, < 0.10
>= 0.8, < 1.0
>= 0.7.4, < 0.10
```

It looks to me like any 0.9.x version of faraday should suffice, including 0.9.0?

I must be missing some fundamental understanding of whats happening here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As I read it faraday-http-cache would like to have faraday 0.8 . Couldnt you share mygem.gemspec or Gemfile?

Comment: sure, i can try and do that. Although i am curious how you arrived at .8. Doesnt the pessimistic operator mean that Bundler will increment the last number as much as possible without stepping up the second to last? See here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator

Comment: @Felix i might be wrong here... bundle update may not be following those rules as they may only be for bundle install..

Comment: did you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html when you update you do not only change the rails version, but follow those guides

Comment: @justGunnar The `twiddle-waka` should make farraday-http-cache like everything between >= 0.8 and =< 0.9 to my knowledge (http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint)